# postgresql performance issues

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, database-performance

my question is about performance with postgresql lookups. 
I have a table members which will hold at least 20 000 000 members and more. 
The system has some special members (about 10 000).
I have logic doing things with single members, requireing me to query 2-3 of these special members either for sure, every time.

The question is: Might i experience performance wins when externalizing those 
10 000 members into an own table, even so they are completely equal? Because the lookup for these runs way faster because there are much less rows??

EDIT:
The queries are as simple as possible. Just query by primary key and joins over foreign keys.

EDIT2: 
To simplify the question. Is there a significant speed difference between querying through primary key from table with 30 000 000+ rows and a table 10 000 rows? Or is it all about proper indexes?

thank you in advance

Comment: If you have proper indexes, I don't see why the lookup would be noticeably faster with another table.  However, this depends greatly on the specific query, so you should edit your question with that information.

Comment: Post an EXPLAIN of your queries, it's just guesswork otherwise.

Comment: To make your proposed table of 10k rows, you're going to have to query your 300M row table anyway.  Your subsequent queries will improve in speed (in the sane way partitioning helps) but it's likely to be a relatively small gain.  Unless you're going to run Many queries against the 10k table, I doubt the gains will be larger than the overhead of creating it.  Equally your code gets more complicated and prone to human error.  This very much sounds like premature optimisation.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with splitting the table at this phase until you have measurements that clearly indicates that the query for VIP members is a bottleneck.

If later you encounter problems in this area you'll have some options to improve performance without changing need to make code changes in your application .

One of them is - separate index for VIP members. 
You can create [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) that will contain only data for VIP members. This would reduce number of lookups approximately log(30000000)/log(10000) ~= 2 times.

Another option is to use table [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) so that your application still thinks it works with one table but in reality it is split into two physical tables.

Answer (score 1):

1. For all your queries run `EXPLAIN your-query-here` and check if indexes are used.
2. Depending how often that table is updated you can create VIEWs in Postgres which basically work as filters.